# How should I represent the type of a string containing a path to a file in type annotations?

Tags: python, typing, type-hinting

I'm writing a library that provides a class that's meant to be subclassed by end users. The class's constructor cares about the types of the arguments of the methods added to the subclass. I want the end users to be able to indicate the arguments' types with type annotations.

One of the things my class cares about is whether an argument is a string that contains a path to a file. Logically, this should be a subtype of `str`, which can be indicated like so:

```
import mylib
from typing import *

FilePath = NewType('FilePath', AnyStr)

class MySubclass(mylib.MyClass):
    def my_method(self, path: FilePath):
        return open(path)
```

But the docstring of `typing.NewType` gives the following examples:

```
from typing import *

UserId = NewType('UserId', int)

def name_by_id(user_id: UserId) -> str:
    ...

name_by_id(42)          # Fails type check
name_by_id(UserId(42))  # OK
```

So, in order for a static type checker to not fail code that uses my library, users would have to do the following:

```
from mylib import *

... # MySubclass defined as above

o = MySubclass()
o.my_method(FilePath('foo/bar.baz'))
```

But I want them to be able to simply do

```
o.my_method('foo/bar.baz')
```

without a static type checker throwing errors. This is more because I am worried about the semantics of the types I'm defining, rather than because of the danger of anybody ever actually using my code *and* bothering to run a static type checker on it.

One solution is to define `FilePath` as

```
FilePath = Union[AnyStr, NewType('FilePath', AnyStr)]
```

but this is confusing to look at, and its `__repr__` is a straight-up lie:

```
>>> FilePath
Union[Anystr, FilePath]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: It's not a lie but just what you asked for. It is also nonsense because your types are basically `AnyStr` anyway.

Comment: Basically `AnyStr`, but not `AnyStr`. The method is supposed to accept a specific subset of `AnyStr`s; specifically, those that are paths to existing files, and are used in the method body as that path. This is a subtype of `AnyStr`; I just don't want end users to have to cast explicitly.

Comment: "The method is supposed to accept a specific subset of AnyStrs" but the type actually accept any string so this convoluted type definition buys you nothing except a nice alias for `AnyStr`.

Comment: Why do you care about all this type business?  Just write good code, document it well, and the rest of it takes care of itself.  I've been writing production Python code for as long as there's been Python, and I've never felt a need to add type declarations to my APIs or other code.  Seems like a gimmick to me.

Comment: @Steve In this case, the annotations have a runtime use. And since they annotations are denoting "type-like" information, I want to make sure that their usage doesn't conflict with common intuition about how types are normally handled in Python annotations. I agree that static type checking for Python is kind of gimmicky, but that's a whole separate conversation.

Comment: @mszegedy.  I didn't mean to sound judgemental.  What I said was purely IMHO, and I'm quite often wrong about things.  I also take your point that I don't understand what you're doing really.  I took a fresh read of your question, I and kinda get that you want your subclasses to convey information up into the superclass.  I can't say that that's not a perfectly valid reason to attach this type information. In my own mind, I still wonder if there's not a more straightforward way to get the behavior you want, but you may be doing exactly the right thing for you.  I hope it all works out for you.

Comment: ...this is what makes computers both fun and frustrating, right?  There are many good (and some bad) ways to do things to get them to perform for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two goals are incompatible: you can't simultaneously specify that your method accepts only a specific path-like objects (or even a specific subtype of str) while allowing the caller to directly pass in some arbitrary str.

You need to pick one of the two.

If you decide to go with the former (specify the method only accepts specific path-like objects), a more palatable alternative to using NewTypes might be to instead switch to having your method accept only [`pathlib.Path` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

class MyClass:
    def my_method(self, x: Path) -> None: ...

MyClass().my_method(Path("foo/bar.baz"))
```

Your callers will still need to convert their strings into these Path objects, but at least now they'll gain some actual runtime benefit from doing so.

If you decide to go with the latter goal (allow users to pass in strings directly), you might as well get rid of all of your NewTypes and switch to using str (or `Union[Text, bytes]` or `AnyStr`) directly. It would be a more honest type signature:

```
class MyClass:
    def my_method(self, x: str) -> None: ...

MyClass().my_method("foo/bar.baz")
```

You could perhaps make this slightly more readable by using type aliases, like so:

```
MaybeAPath = str

class MyClass:
    def my_method(self, x: MaybeAPath) -> None: ...

MyClass().my_method("foo/bar.baz")
```

...but this is a readability improvement only. To be fully type-safe, your code and your subclasser's code would still need to include some error handling if they receive some random string that can't be parsed as a path.

I personally bias towards using pathlib.Path objects everywhere, for what it's worth.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll go with `pathlib.Path`. I guess in order for a type to exist, it needs to be possible to statically determine whether something is that type. There is also the anarchic option of just using `NewType('Path', AnyStr)` and allowing the caller to pass `AnyStr`s anyway; after all, PEP 3107 reads, "Function annotations are nothing more than a way of associating arbitrary Python expressions with various parts of a function at compile-time." But I don't think I want to do that.